# Django, South, and Guardian: Migrate

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-guardian

I have two users, mh00h1 and mh00h2. I also have modelA that defines the following in my models.py:

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ('read','read'),
        ('write','write'),
    )
```

From a shell, I went to set permissions:

```
>>>> frhde = create modelA instance
>>>> assign_perm('read', mh00h2, frhde)

DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'codename': u'read', 'content_type': <ContentType: modelA>}
```

I realized that `South` didn't migrate my models after I added `class Meta` to `modelA` and confirmed this. Changing `read` to `read2` shows that `South` does not detect the change.

```
$ /manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto

Running migrations for myapp:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for myapp.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for guardian:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for guardian.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

How can I get schematicmigration to correctly update the database, or is there a better way to do this that does not require redoing the whole database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `./manage.py syncdb --all`, or create a signal like in [this post](http://devwithpassion.com/felipe/south-django-permissions/).

Comment: You can also use [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)'s `update_permissions` management command.