# Django Assign-perm w/ Post-Save Signal

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-signals

I have a django model named `archive` that is tied to a `group` (django auth) by a foreign key. In order for a user to edit something in this archive, they must have permission to do so through `django-guardian`. I can link an archive with a group as shown in my code below, however, I need to be able to set per-object (archive)-permissions with each group as well. I am seeking to do this using a `post_save` or `post_delete` signal (to properly prevent orphan permissions).

In other words, here are the steps I want to accomplish. Visit Admin page. Create/Edit an instance of `Archive`. Specify on that page what user-group will be associated with that particular `Archive.` Upon saving that instance, Django should automatically authenticate the specified group with 'read' permissions for that instance of Archive.

What file would I store `Archive_post_save_handler` in? models.py? As it stands, I can't assign group permissions because I think I am having trouble passing objects through my functions. How can I accomplish this? As a bonus question, will this hook also apply if I edited the model through a shell?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.db.models.signals import *
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Archive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True)
    Group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, help_text='A group of users that are allowed access to the archive. This should typically be called the same thing as the archive name.')

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('read', 'Read Archive'),
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

@receiver(post_save, sender=Archive)
def Archive_post_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwarks):
    group = Group.objects.get(name=instance.Group)
    assign_perm('read', group, instance) #what I primarily want to accomplish in this question is on this line
```

Comment: my problem seems to resolve around the phrase `archive` at `assign_perm('read', group, archive)`. I don't think I have the right variable there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code you pasted here will cause a recursive calling `Archive_post_save_handler`, because the last line of code will also trigger another `post_save` signal. You should get the `created` argument from the kwargs to test if the instance is created for the first time.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I do get an error: `maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp`. I still need help getting my assign_perm to work as well though if you have any idea; that weighs more heavily with me. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Well, the signal will trigger from django admin or django shell. As to your problem, 
1. Have you assigned users to the `group` instance? 
2. `group = Group.objects.get(name=instance.Group)`, why not just `group = instance.Group`

Comment: Users are assigned to the group instance. I'm getting a `does not exist error:` `Permission matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'codename': u'read', 'content_type': <ContentType: archive>}`. Is there something else that belongs in place of the last `instance` of my code?

Comment: nevermind: got it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117687/django-south-and-guardian-migrate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error tells that there is no permission record of `read` in the db. If the code bellow is added after `./manage.py syncdb`, there will be the problem. 

`
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('read', 'Read Archive'),
        )
`

You should insert a row in table `auth_permission` or drop the Archive table and run `./manage.py syncdb`.